# Using Document data type for XML processing in Talend

Tags: xml, talend

I'm confused about the standard procedure for processing XML files in Talend. I read about the recommendation to use the Document data type as show in the attached screenshot. But there seems to be another way: a separate schema column per xml node. What is the difference between the both approaches. Are there advantages/disadvantages? Are there scenarios where only one of both leads to success? What is the preferred way for XML-to-XML transformations with many loops? Do both ways run with mappings (tMap/tXMLMap)?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The mapping allows you to break down your XML into another data structure so it can be further manipulated by other components or used by non document handling components.

If you specify the XPath to get to each of your elements or attributes you can then remap those in a tXMLMap or simply push the selected data into an RDBMS or flat file.